# First run of script process time

Tags: php, mysql

In an admin application for the local food bank, I've built a PHP script to generate a set of monthly reporting statistics from a MySQL database.  It appears that if the script has not been run for some uncertain amount of time it will take several seconds to run.  Once run, subsequent runs of the script will take a fraction of a second.  I'm trying to figure out what factors cause the lengthy first run and whether I have any control of them.  The behavior is comparable between my development system and the food bank's host so it's not just a local phenomenon.

I've experimented with "flush tables" and "reset query cache" but I cannot reproduce the long run.  Nor does shutting down and restarting the MySQL server (only possible on the development system) make the run longer.

Where else might I look?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to give us more to work with, right now all we can do is make random wild guesses

Comment: You also have to take into account the OS Filesystem cache and virtual memory systems.  The PHP files will be read from disc the first time, but from the filesystem cache on subsequent runs.  The PHP engine will also have been read into memory and will be invoked from there instead of loaded from disc.

Comment: I can see how disk access might be a factor for cli.  It cannot explain the behavior at the remote host where PHP is used to get initial and subsequent times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first port of call in circumstances like this would be to profile the script to see what's taking the time. You say you can replicate the problem locally. In that case get yourself a profiler ([xDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and the [Zend Debugger](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/features#debug) can both profile scripts, there may be others) and profile your script to see where the time is going.

Comment: An interesting concept - but I'm not clear on how xDebug will help me focus on the first run process time.  Any reference where I can read up on this?

Comment: @geoB See the link to xDebug. It explains how to get the profiling up and running. The output of that should show you what's consuming the most time and help you investigate how to improve it.

Comment: Doh!  I'm on it.  I expect it will take a few days before I learn anything useful.  Will report on findings.  Thnx.  g

Comment: Wow!  A v. cool tool.  While I haven't gotten an answer to my original question yet, I doubt there's any better way to find it.  So I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks.  g